# How to read data fromMysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have a same problem where read data from mysql and store it in an array.
I have table something like this

```
id     engineering     science      language
_____________________________________________

1      chemical        bio           english
2      electrical      chemistry     malay 
3      mechanical      astronomy     spanish
```

How to I read for example all the data from engineering and store it in an array? Can I do any hashing in PHP, or associative array already include this hashing function.
Please help.

Comment: See this question may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697515/how-to-store-row-column-of-mysql-data-in-array

Comment: Hi Anshu, i'm trying to do the searching whereby search with some text stored in mysql table like above based on the category. but i need to include some hashing which faster then text searching. Im not sure whether PHP have any hashing function since associative array already store the data with Id .how do i continue with that?

Comment: hi can anyone give me better option for this urgently please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A barebones example using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

```
// connect to your database
$mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// setup your query
$query = "SELECT * FROM engineering ";
$results = array();
// execute your query
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    // the query was successful; iterate through each result fetching an
    // associative array and add it to the `$results` list
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    $result->free();
}
$mysqli->close();

// process all results in `$results` array! (simple output)
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['id'] . ' ' . $result['engineering'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. but how to display the result of this array?

Comment: @vaani That's completely up to you. You can loop through the array with a `foreach` and do whatever it is you want. I've updated my answer with a simple example of the `foreach` and outputting selected columns.

Comment: hi newfurniturey thanks for the feedback. Im trying to compile with your updated code but im getting some error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\AppServ\www\array3.php on line 45 showing at the last line echo $result['id'] . ' ' . $result['engineering']

Comment: ok i able to correct the error but yet the output is not as what i want. it supposed to print the array element but it just print the word array only.