# Right way to fetch and display massive php variables via html

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

When we are supposed to fetch some 200 database entries using php and display them in the page using html, what is the best way to do so. Right now i am doing like this`<?php echo $variable1?;>,,,,<?php echo $variable200;?>` and feel like its bit slow to load. Any alternative please?

model:

```
$query_str = "select *from table where sl_no='$report_id' and code='$code'";
$row=$query->row_array();
    return $row;
```

controller:

```
$reports=$this->patient_model->fetch_previous_reports($pat_lab_id);
    echo json_encode($reports);
```

Comment: Need more code to see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: fetch the value in array format. and list out

Comment: Use Foreach -- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php to loop through the array values, so you have `$var[0]` ... `$var[199]` as an array of organised data

Comment: And use pagination. Divide data set into parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the variables and store it in a `array`. Refer to this question, [How to store row/column of mysql data in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697515/how-to-store-row-column-of-mysql-data-in-array), on how to store MySQL values in array.

More information on `array`: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp.

Then, echo all the values stored in the array:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: echo implode('<br>', $array);

Comment: @MaximColesnic Yup, missed out line break, thanks :)